# How to check if object has some particular PUBLIC selector at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, respondstoselector

I need to find out if some particular object has some particular selector AND if i may call it. I need to check it at runtime. I know about `respondsToSelector:` but unfortunaly it also checks protected interface of class.

I need to check if the selector exists AND if it's public. Is there a way i can do it?

Comment: Why do you need this? I don't think this information is maintained after compilation...

Comment: @Wain it's pretty hard to explain why do i need this in few lines. I have a very complex system for localization of my app . There is a reason why i cant use standart ways for localization. Checking public selectors of objects at runtime is part of this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C there is no concept of public, private or protected methods. Only IDE can incorporate those concepts to provide some OOP when developing but at runtime everything goes, so there is no standard way to do this.

What you could do is to subclass (or make a category with associated objects) NSObject, create array with public methods selectors where every next subclass adds its public methods to this array and either use your own method or swizzle respondsToSelector method to check for match in your array.